# Why are the seconds/minutes/hours units are universally used, while other measures have several units?

Tags: time, conventions, units, si-units, metrology

There are several units to measure length like meter, foot, and rod. The same is true for weight. While time seem to have a universal unit which is the second. Was there other measures of time that didn't survive? What led to time being a special measure where almost all the different world organization uses the same unit?

Comment: It's a great question but it also falls a bit outside of physics - It might be better suited to ask https://history.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question about physics

Comment: 60 is divisible by 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 12, 15, 30...so it's been a popular base for time. (similarly  for "degrees").

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_time#:~:text=This%20term%20is%20often%20used,day)%2C%20as%20opposed%20to%20the shows another system...

Comment: To answer your question, since it was closed rather than moved, time is uniquely standardized because it was standardized long before all the others. Unlike weight and distance, there is a unique, universal quantity that everyone can agree on: the day. And the only way to get more hours in the day (for now) is to make the hours shorter. 24 hours was chosen because 12 is highly composite and the day is naturally divided into two halves. 60 minutes was chosen because 60 is highly composite,  and by the time we needed the granularity of minutes, and seconds, we needed a lot more than 12.

Comment: The 24/60/60 division of the day then became a practical standard throughout the Mediterranean, where it was picked up by Judaism, and then Christianity and Islam, and then all the places they conquered, until, by the time the metric system was born, there were very few hold outs, and none in Europe, the Middle East or North Africa. While the French Revolutionaries tried to decimalize time, no one cared, and reverted to the "universal" standard that was already in place. And that's why no one talks about "kiloseconds"